# Compiler doesn't want to execute a chunk of code

Tags: java, arrays, methods, compilation

I have a method that opens a file and turns each line into an object (it can be either a DVD or a Livre, both under the superclass Document) that is then put in an Array. but for some reason after these lines :

```java
try {
    tabChaineSafe[k] = tabChaine[k];
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException erreurarray) {
    tabChaineSafe[k] = "Information indisponible.";
}
```

the compiler just skips the rest. Therefore, the whole array ends up being full of nulls. Here's a gif of me using the debugger to see what happens.

https://gyazo.com/a09c2b617ba94f12dce1165420d528dd

Here's the full code of the method :

```java
public static Document[] remplirTabDocs(Document[] tabDocs) {
    String ligne = new String();
    String[] tabChaine;
    String[] tabChaineSafe = new String[6];
    FileInputStream file = lectureFichier("doc.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    int j = 0; //compteur pour le tableau d'objets
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        ligne = scan.nextLine();
        tabChaine = ligne.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChaine.length; i++) { //nettoyage des
            //espaces
            tabChaine[i] = tabChaine[i].trim();      //tableau des infos
            /*
             ** On va maintenant transférer ces String dans un nouveau
             ** String[] parce que parfois, il n'y a pas de description
             ** et cela peut causer des erreurs.
             */
            for (int k = 0; k < tabChaineSafe.length; k++) {
                try {
                    tabChaineSafe[k] = tabChaine[k];
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException erreurarray) {
                    tabChaineSafe[k] = "Information indisponible.";
                }
                //
                if (tabChaineSafe[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Livre")) {
                    /*
                     ** Étape 1 : Vérifier si un ouvrage de ce nom est
                     ** déjà répertorié.
                     */
                    boolean existant;
                    existant = checkExistants
                            (tabChaineSafe[1], tabDocs);
                    if (existant) {
                        int numDocExistant = lequelExistant
                                (tabChaineSafe[1]
                                        , tabDocs);
                        tabDocs[numDocExistant].copiesDispo++;
                    } else {
                        Livre livre = new Livre(tabChaineSafe[0],
                                tabChaineSafe[1],
                                tabChaineSafe[2],
                                tabChaineSafe[3],
                                tabChaineSafe[4],
                                tabChaineSafe[5],
                                1);
                    }
                } else if (tabChaineSafe[0].equalsIgnoreCase("DVD")) {
                    /*
                     ** Étape 1 : Vérifier si un ouvrage de ce nom est
                     ** déjà répertorié.
                     */
                    boolean existant;
                    existant = checkExistants(tabChaineSafe[1],
                            tabDocs);
                    if (existant) {
                        int numDocExistant = lequelExistant
                                (tabChaineSafe[1]
                                        , tabDocs);
                        tabDocs[numDocExistant].copiesDispo++;
                    } else {
                        try {
                            int nbDisquesInt = Integer.parseInt
                                    (tabChaineSafe[3]);
                            DVD dvd = new DVD(tabChaineSafe[0],
                                    tabChaineSafe[1],
                                    tabChaineSafe[2],
                                    nbDisquesInt, 1);
                        } catch (NumberFormatException nbfmtexc) {
                            /*
                             ** Aucune instance n'est générée
                             */
                        }
                    }
                }
                //
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    fermetureFichier(file);
    return tabDocs;
}
```

I have no idea why it does that. Also for context yes transferring the values of tabChaine to tabChaineSafe is necessary because sometimes a line in a document has an info missing and I wanna avoid this resulting in the attribute being assigned null.

Comment: What happens if `tabChaine.length` is less than the length of `tabChaineSafe`? You will get a bunch of null values. What happens if `tabChaine` in never filled because of input issues with your scanner inputs? You will have an array of null values. Do some debugging by printing values to the console to work out what is being read from the scanner, and if `tabChaine` is actually being filled with values. Also, the reason your debugger skips down like that is that your code doesn't satisfy the following if or else if statements.

Comment: it's the reason i put a try catch , tabChaine & tabChaineSafe both work fine when i check with the debugger variables window

Comment: There is clearly an issue here where the `if` and `else if` conditions are not being met, for example `if ( tabChaineSafe[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Livre") )`, does tabChaineSafe[0] ever equal "Livre", well obviously not if we go by your debugger gif. Please edit your question to include more information, either include some sample values that you are putting into the scanner or an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can test, or edit your question to show the debugger values after the try/catch block.

Comment: Compilers don't execute your code. They compile it. Be precise. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues that will need fixing, but lets focus on the main ones. Your code currently reads a line from a scanner and splits it up into an array `tabChaine`. Then using a `for` loop you assign that data to `tabChaineSafe`, but then you use another nested `for` loop to process that data, however, that loop should **NOT** go inside the previous loop because it is pointless and will process the data multiple times over. Once the loop is fixed we can use `System.out.println(...);` to make sure the values are working.

The second issue is that your code does not enter the `if` or `else if` statements:

```
if ( tabChaineSafe[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Livre") ) {
    //Code hidden for clarity
}
else if ( tabChaineSafe[0].equalsIgnoreCase("DVD") ) {
    //Code hidden for clarity
}
```

This is because you are NOT getting the values you expect from your file at the index you expect. We can check that it is working by using some sample data `ligne = "Livre,value1,value2,value";`

Consider the following working example that puts everything together and prints the correct output using the sample data:

```
while (scan.hasNext())
{
    //Hide this line for now so that we can check our sample data:
    //ligne = scan.nextLine();

    //Sample data to use for testing:
    ligne = "Livre,value1,value2,value";

    //Print the data to console to see if it is loading tho correct thing
    System.out.println("Data loaded from scanner: \r\n"+ligne);

    //Split the data
    tabChaine = ligne.split(",");
    
    //Run the loop up to 6 times using "&& i < 6"
    //This will help prevent index out of bounds issues
    for (int i = 0; i < tabChaine.length || i < 6; i++)
    {
        //Trim the data and assign it directly to the safe loop if the index is not out of bounds
        if(i < tabChaine.length)
            tabChaineSafe[i] = tabChaine[i].trim();
        //If the index is out of bounds then assign a value
        else
            tabChaineSafe[i] = "no value found";
    }
    
    //Now that the loop is complete we can create the objects
    //This must be done outside of the loop above
    if (tabChaineSafe[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Livre"))
    {
        //Debug the values using the console:
        System.out.println("The if statement worked, and found " + tabChaineSafe[0] + " at tabChaineSafe[0]");

        //New you can do the rest of your code
        //boolean existant;
        //existant = checkExistants(tabChaineSafe[1], tabDocs);
        //if (existant)
        //{
        //    int numDocExistant = lequelExistant(tabChaineSafe[1],tabDocs);
        //    tabDocs[numDocExistant].copiesDispo++;
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    livre = new Livre(tabChaineSafe[0],tabChaineSafe[1],tabChaineSafe[2],tabChaineSafe[3],tabChaineSafe[4],tabChaineSafe[5],1);
        //}
    }
    else if ( tabChaineSafe[0].equalsIgnoreCase("DVD") ) {
        System.out.println("DVD found");

        //Your code here
        //Removed for clarity
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Unknown type fonud " + tabChaineSafe[0]);
    }
}
fermetureFichier(file);
return tabDocs;
```

And using our sample data it will correctly enter the `if` statement and print the output to the console:

> Data loaded from scanner:
>
> Livre,value1,value2,value
>
> The if statement worked, and found Livre at tabChaineSafe[0]

Now that we know that the above code is working, you need to check that you file "doc.txt" actually contains the data you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I really hadn't realised how illogical what I did was.